mi aplicacion en javaFX no inicia únicamente en netbeans
Soy nuevo en programacion. Estoy usando Netbeans 11, y he instalado el javaFX jdk 21, siguiendo todos los pasos y ya he probado con una aplicacion basica en usando Java with Ant, y me funciona perfectamente. Pero ahora al intentar correr una aplicacion simple de TipCalculator, me sale lo siguiente:
ant -f D:\\Homework\\JAVA\\TipCalculator jfxsa-run


jfxsa-run:


Result: 255


BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

como ven no hay errores en el programa, pero el programa no inicia correctamente. Luego probe abrirlo desde la terminal y me inicia perfectamente, solo en netbeans la aplicacion no inicia. Probe a reinstalar el jdk y el netbeans y nada. Agradeceria mucho que alguien me de aunquesea una pista para poder correr el programa.
Tengo el netbeans 21, y incluso si creo un nuevo programa JavaFX Application, y lo inicio sin hacer ningun cambio, obtengo el mismo resultado.

ant -f C:\Users\Joao\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication5 jfxsa-run jfxsa-run: Result: 255 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Por lo tanto, no creo que tenga nada que ver con el programa.

ok, perdon me equivoque al escribir. Tengo el netbeans 21, y incluso si creo un nuevo programa JavaFX Application, y lo inicio sin hacer ningun cambio, obtengo el mismo resultado.
ant -f C:\Users\Joao\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication5 jfxsa-run
jfxsa-run:
Result: 255
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
Por lo tanto, no creo que tenga nada que ver con el programa.

tal vez tu aplicación TipCaculator no tiene un main... no sabría decirte sin ver el código

Estas usando netbeans 11 con JDK21 cuando netbeans va por la versión 21 también, deberías actualizar el netbeans desde su pagina web.
